# Øksendal's SDEs Exercise 2.17

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am trying to solve part (a) of this exercise, which states that

$$E\left(\left[\sum_{t_k\leq t} \left(\Delta B_k\right)^2 - t\right]^2 \right) =2\sum_{t_k\leq t}(\Delta t_k)^2 ~,
$$

where $0=t_0<\dots<t_n=t$. What I've done so far is squaring in the LHS and taking the expectancy, so I get

$$
\sum E\left(\left(\Delta B_k\right)^4\right)-t^2 +t^2
$$

I'm stuck at computing the expectancy that is left, this is probably elementary but I haven't succeeded.

Comment: can you give some more background information about this?

Comment: Oh yes sorry $B_t$ is a 1-dimensional Brownian motion. Probably the author is implicitly assuming that $B_0=0$ too.

Comment: By definition $B_t-B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$ for any $s \leq $. What does this tell you about the variance of $B_t-B_s$?

Comment: @saz OK thanks to your hint I could finnish the proof, so we have $E((\Delta B_k)^4)=Var((\Delta B_k)^2)= 2(\Delta t_k)^2$ since $(\Delta B_k)^2$ has a chi-squared distribution of 1 degree of freedom.

Comment: @mathma, if you have figured out how to sold your problem, create an answer to your own question with the solution and accept it (mark it as correct). So that others know it has been solved and to help someone with a similar problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I arrived at the following solution using @saz's suggestion. First we square
$$E[(\sum_{t_k\leq t} (\Delta B_k)^2 -t)^2]=\sum_{t_k\leq t}E((\Delta B_k)^4) - t \sum_{t_k\leq t}E((\Delta B_k)^2)+t^2$$
here we are using the fact that the increments are independent. We have that
$$Var((\Delta B_k)^2)=E((\Delta B_k)^4)-E((\Delta B_k)^2)^2=E((\Delta B_k)^4)-(\Delta t_k)^2$$
And using the fact that $(\Delta B_k)^2$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with 1 degree of freedom, we get $Var((\Delta B_k)^2)=2(\Delta t_k)^2$. So $E((\Delta B_k)^4)=(\Delta t_k)^2$.
So now we have
$$E[(\sum_{t_k\leq t} (\Delta B_k)^2 -t)^2]=\sum_{t_k\leq t}(\Delta t_k)^2 - t \sum_{t_k\leq t}\Delta t_k +t^2=\sum_{t_k\leq t} (\Delta t_k)^2$$
Since the second is a telescoping sum. 
I might be mistaken at some point since the 2 doesn't appear, but maybe it's a typo?